# preg_match Facebook Photo URL

Tags: facebook, preg-match

im realy sucking in preg_match things.

I realy hope someone can help me.

I want to check the url for the bold text this -> http://a2.**sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net**/*somechars.jpg

I have a form, where user can post Picture. But i only want, that they can post pictures from Facebook Foto. I alredy check the link, if it is .jpg/.jpeg/png.

```
$is_pic = (bool) preg_match('/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|w?bmp|e)\z/i', $path_parse);
$file_type= ".jpeg, .jpg, .png";
if ($is_pic == true && strcmp ($pathparts['filename'], $file_type)) {
....}
```

Can plz someone help me with the facebook URL? i realdy tried hard, but i failed :( I need to preg_match URL, if it is realy from the domain.

Comment: If you just need to know that the URL includes that bold part then try... `$is_pic = (bool) preg_match('/sphotos\.ak\.fbcdn\.net/i', $path_parse);`

Comment: thanks, i will add this to my code :)

but to make it safer, how i can check the url, that the url is realy from facebook-foto?

Comment: What is facebook-foto? Is that part of the URL?

Comment: all the url from the fotos that you upload to facebook looks like this:  http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/*somechars.jpg - with facebook foto I mean this kind of url :)

i tried your code but when i add a facebooko-foto-url i get false.

Comment: what's the url you tried it with?

Comment: eg. : http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/p480x480/524936_353401681385716_243355085723710_939664_1788013879_n.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path_parse = "http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/p480x480/524936_353401681385716_243355085723710_939664_1788013879_n.jpg";

$is_pic = (bool) preg_match('/sphotos\.ak\.fbcdn\.net/i', $path_parse);

if ($is_pic) {
    echo("it matched");
}
```